# Show there exist three distinct positive real numbers a, b, c, none of which are integers, such that all of ab, ac, bc and abc are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

This question is from "Chartrand, Polimeni and Zhang Mathematical Proofs": Chapter 8, Exercise 8.81.

Since this is an existence question, a simple example suffices to complete a proof. The book provides

Proof Let $a = 6/5$, $b = 10/3$ and $c = 15/2$. Then $ab = 4$, $ac = 9$, $bc = 25$ and $abc = 30$

**I am interested however in specifying the general conditions for existence.** While trying to solve the exercise I could not easily come up with an example, so I tried to find the general form for a, b and c so that an existence is possible.

**My question is how would one go about this?**

From the solution one can see for example the following relationships:
\begin{align}
a=6/5=p/q 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
b = 2q/(p/2) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
c = 3q/(p/3) 
\end{align}
etc.

Also note that $ab = 4$, $ac = 9$, $bc = 25$ are all perfect squares. Now I wonder if that is a precondition as well but not sure how to go about showing this.

Comment: Squares?  No...If $(a,b,c)$ is a good triple, then so is $(na,b,c)$ for any $n\in \mathbb Z$ (well, at least any $n$ for which $na\not \in \mathbb Z$).  So take your triple and multiply $a$ by $7$.

Comment: As an exercise, I suggest:  prove that if $(a,b,c)$ is a good triple, then $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q$.  That's true, but I don't think it's entirely obvious.

Comment: thanks. What exactly is a "good triple"? you mean one that is a solution to this exercise?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: No problem.  Should say:  In the counterexample I gave, of course $\gcd(ab,ac)=7>1$.  You could tighten your assumptions and require that $\gcd(ab,bc)=1, \gcd(ab,ac)=1, \gcd(bc,ac)=1$.  Maybe in that case they are squares?  Haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $x:=ab$, $y:=bc$, $z:=ca$ and $p:=abc$. Note that
$$
a=xz/p, \quad 
b=xy/p, \quad \text{ and }\quad 
c=yz/p.
$$
Then it is enough to find four values of $x,y,z,p$ such that $a,b,c$ are not integers. The relation between those integers is that
$
p^2=xyz.
$
If you want that $a,b,c\notin \mathbb{Z}$, then the integer $p$ does not divide any of the products $xy$, $yz$, $zx$.

A class of examples: Pick three pairwise coprime integers $r,s,t \ge 2$ and set
$$
x=r^2, y=s^2, z=t^2 \,\,\text{ and }\,\,p:=rst.
$$
Then
$$
a=rt/s, \quad 
b=rs/t, \quad \text{ and }\quad 
c=st/r
$$
are not integers.

Comment: Thanks. I think several key steps I missed out on in my understanding were the relationship $p^2 = xyz$, that p should not divide any of the products xy.. etc. and especially also to select $r,s,t $ such that they are pairwise coprime.

Answer (score 2):

We'll look at $a, b, c$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $p_i$ be the set of prime numbers that appear in $a, b, c$, with at least one strictly positive or strictly negative exponent among $a, b,$ or $c$.
Let $a_i, b_i, c_i$ be those exponents, i.e. $a = \prod_i p_i^{a_i}$, etc.

In order to meet the question, we must have:

- some $a_i$, some $b_i$, some $c_i$ are strictly negative (otherwise $a, b$ or $c$ is an integer)
- $\forall i, a_i + b_i \ge 0, b_i + c_i \ge 0, c_i + a_i \ge 0$
  Note that this entails $\forall i, a_i + b_i + c_i \ge 0$, i.e. $abc$ is an integer, too.

Given any $a_i$, it is always possible to find $b_i$ and $c_i$ that meet the conditions, which are rather large.

For a given $i$, we can represent $X_i = (a_i, b_i, c_i)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
The conditions "$\forall i, a_i + b_i \ge 0, b_i + c_i \ge 0, c_i + a_i \ge 0$" are equivalent to: $X_i$ is in a cone, intersection of 3 semi-spaces.
The condition "some $a_i$, some $b_i$, some $c_i$ are strictly negative" means that $\exists i, X_i$ is not in the first orthant.

Note also that given a solution, it is always possible to find an infinity of other solutions by changing the $p_i$.

An example:
$(a_1, b_1, c_1) = (3, -2, 4)$
$(a_2, b_2, c_2) = (-1, 1, 2)$
$(a_3, b_3, c_3) = (1, 1, -1)$
with $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 5$
This gives: $a = \frac {40} 3, b = \frac {15} 4, c = \frac {144} 5$
$ab = 50, bc = 108, ca = 384, abc = 1440$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach starts by observing that $a$, $b$, and $c$ must be rational but not integer, in which case we can express them them as $$a = \frac {a_n} {a_d}, b = \frac {b_n} {b_d}, c = \frac {c_n} {c_d}$$, with each numerator $x_n$ being a nonzero integer, each denominator $x_d$ being an integer greater than 1, and corresponding $x_n$, $x_d$ pairs being coprime.

We then observe that $ab = \frac {a_n}{a_d}\frac {b_n}{b_d} = m$ for some integer $m$, and therefore ${a_n}{b_n} = m{a_d}{b_d}$.  But by construction, $a_n$ and $a_d$ have no common factors, so $a_d$ must divide $b_n$.  Likewise, $b_d$ must divide $a_n$.  By analogous arguments, it follows from $ac$ and $bc$ being integers that $a_d$ and $b_d$ each divide $c_n$, and $c_d$ divides both $a_n$ and $b_n$.

In that case, there must be nonzero integers $n_a$, $n_b$, and $n_c$ such that $$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm} a_n = n_a \lcm(b_d, c_d), b_n = n_b \lcm(a_d, c_d), c_n = n_c \lcm(a_d, b_d)$$ The ($x_n$, $x_d$) pairs are coprime by construction, so $a_d$ must be coprime with all factors of $a_n$, including $n_a$ and $\lcm(b_d, c_d)$ in particular, and therefore also with $b_d$ and $c_d$. Analogously, $b_d$ must be coprime with $n_b$ and $c_d$, and $c_d$ with $n_c$.

Since the denominators are all pairwise coprime, their pairwise least common multiples are just their products.  Using that, together with the two previous sets of equations, we find that

---

**Every solution must have the form**
$$a = \frac{n_a b_d c_d}{a_d}, b = \frac{n_b a_d c_d}{b_d}, c = \frac{n_c a_d b_d}{c_d}$$
, where

- $a_d$, $b_d$, and $c_d$ are mutually coprime integers greater than 1, and
- $n_a$, $n_b$, and $n_c$ are nonzero integers, coprime with $a_d$, $b_d$, and $c_d$, respectively.

---

Now consider the product $a b c$. Substituting from the previous formulas, we get $$abc = \frac{n_a b_d c_d}{a_d} \frac{n_b a_d c_d}{b_d} \frac{n_c a_d b_d}{c_d} = n_a n_b n_c a_d b_d c_d$$, which is an integer. Thus, **the conditions above are not only necessary, but also sufficient** for $a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfying the requirements.

***Example***: if we choose the first three primes for the denominators and 1 for $n_a$, $n_b$, and $n_c$ then that gives us
$$ a = \frac{1 \times 3 \times 5}{2},  b = \frac{1 \times 2 \times 5}{3}, c = \frac{1 \times 2 \times 3}{5}$$, or
$$ a = \frac{15}{2},  b = \frac{10}{3}, c = \frac{6}{5}$$
Looks familiar ....

Comment: Please use the [editing sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) if you need to make many edits over a short period.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,q,r$ be three distinct positive integers such that $pqr$ is a perfect square $s^2,$ then the three distinct real numbers
$$a:=\frac sr,\;b:=\frac sq,\;c:=\frac sp$$
satisfy
$$ab=p,\;ac=q,\;bc=r,\;abc=s,$$
and none of them is an integer as long as $p,q,r$ don't divide $s.$